# C#/.NET equivalent for Java's Matcher.matches() and Matcher.lookingAt()

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm looking for a way to decide if a single regular expression matches a whole string, start of the string, or a part of it in C#.

In Java, you can construct a `Matcher` object, and use the methods `matches()` to check if it is a match for the whole input, `lookingAt()` to see if it matches the start of the input, and `find()` to see if there is any match from within the strung at all.

In .NET, I can use `Match.Success` to see if there is any match, and check `Match.Index` and `Match.Length` for the above conditions.

The problem is, it does not try to match the whole input if a smaller match is found. For example, if the input "1234" is presented to the Regex `@"\d{2}|\d{4}"`, it will match the first two digits.

In such a case, I need to have another `Regex` constructed with the pattern `@"^(\d{2}|\d{4})$"` to test for the whole input, and then test the other one to see if it matches the beginning.

Isn't there a way to tell the same `Regex` class to prefer whole-input matches, so that I won't need to create (and compile) another Regex for this reason?

---

EDIT: The question is not about the pattern, it is just an example to show what I mean.

Comment: That is a different expression, it accepts a 3-digit input too. (it means between 2 and four digits, not either of them). Plus, the question is not about the pattern, it is just an example to show the difference. - edit: this is a reply to a removed comment that suggested \d{2,4}

Comment: Can't you just swap the order i.e. `@"^(\d{4}|\d{2})$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no "only match at the beginning" or "only match the entire string" regex method in .NET. You do need to construct this behaviour using anchors.

In a way, I much prefer this over what Java does for two reasons:

- *Many* people are confused by `.matches()` because they don't know it has to match the entire string. I've seen at least a dozen questions on SO about this exact problem.
- Why keep the same functionality redundantly in two different places? You have anchors in regex grammars already, so why make them implicit in some (sometimes misleadingly-named) methods? (I'm talking to you, Python, and your `re.search()` vs. `re.match()`<sup>*</sup>).

That said, it's also very easy to do:

- `@"\A(?:"` + original regex + `")"` --> `lookingAt()` (now who thought of *that* name)?
- `@"\A(?:"` + original regex + `@")\z"` --> `matches()`

---

<sup>*</sup> `re.match()` behaves like Java's `lookingAt()`, not like `matches()`, in case you were wondering.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I need to construct different instances of Regex for the different checks? (And btw, I'm totally with you on the naming thing... the first time I saw the lookingAt method, I was wondering what CAN it mean...)

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I'm saying :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll just keep the question open to see if there's anything else (before marking this as an answer)... Plus, I remember that I checked the Java's implementation of `matches()` and it uses anchors too. I need to re-check to see how exactly is it implemented.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't it be a LOT more efficient to use the original regex and test for `match.Success && match.Length == inputStr.Length` to mimic Java's `matches()` method?

Comment: @NightOwl888: I guess it depends on context. Let's assume the regex is very time-consuming and matches somewhere in the middle of the string. Then performing the match first and checking length later would definitely be much less performant than a regex that can immediately figure out that it doesn't match at the start of the string, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Match / Regex.IsMatch ?
It returns a Match object with subcollections.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch` returns true if any match (on any part of the input) is found. `Regex.Match` returns a collection of matches. For the example that I mentioned in the question text, `Regex.Match` returns two matches, one for position 0..2, and one for the position 2..4. It never returns a match for the whole string.

Comment: Ah ok. It's so simple ... Just use a real Regex ! Try this: \d{2,}

Comment: The syntax i used is in the Quantifiers section: "Matches the previous element at least n times."