# Java matchesAt() equivalent in C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, regex

I have already discovered the question [C#/.NET equivalent for Java's Matcher.matches() and Matcher.lookingAt()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12547528/), but the prescribed answer for lookingAt() there does not seem to work.

All of the [lookingAt() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()) I can find seems to indicate that the `lookingAt()` method matches from the beginning of the "region" (although it isn't quite clear if "region" is synonymous with "the string").

I have an example set of tests that I put together in both Java and .NET, but I am getting different results.

### Java

```
@Test
public void TestRegex()
{
    String input = "자\uD83E"; // "자";
    String regex = ". () [\uD800-\uDFFF]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

    Matcher m = matcher.reset(input);
    Boolean matches = m.lookingAt(); // Returns false
}
```

### .NET

```
[Test]
public void TestRegex()
{
    String input = @"\A(?:" + "자\uD83E" + ")"; // "자" 
    String regex = ". () [\uD800-\uDFFF]";
    Regex pattern = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    Match m = pattern.Match(input);
    Boolean matches = m.Success; // Returns true
}
```

I have ruled out any issues with whitespace or that strange empty capturing group - I get the same results whether they exist or not.

I have also tried changing the regex in .NET to `"자\uD83E"` and using `m.Success && m.Index == 0` as the condition, but the result is exactly the same. And of course, I tried both with string literals and hexadecimal characters and the result is the same.

> To be clear, I am porting an application from Java to .NET. I am trying to find the equivalent functionality to `lookingAt()` in .NET.

So what do I need to change in .NET to make it act the same as `.lookingAt()` in Java? More importantly, why is this particular case returning `false` in Java, as I would expect it to be `true` like in .NET?

In case it matters, I am using .NET Standard 1.3 and Java 1.8 with 1.6 compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you need to use `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag to allow comments and arbitrary whitespaces in your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

You can also use `(?x)` at the start of regex for same effect:

```
String regex = "(?x). () [\uD800-\uDFFF]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

Now `matches` will show `true` for Java code.

---

Now to make `.NET` regex equivalent of `lookngAt()` of Java just use start anchor:

```
String regex = @"\A. () [\uD800-\uDFFF]";
```

Note that you're using anchor in input string, not in regex.

Comment: Hmm...so without it I would need to have a literal space character just like without the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` in .NET?

Comment: Yes that's right. `Pattern.COMMENTS` of `Java` is pretty close to what `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` does for `.NET` (except that Java flag allows comments also in regex)

Comment: So it looks like I goofed when I put the tests together - I had the anchor in the regex in the original code. But I also assumed because there were spaces in the regex that Java would ignore them and that is where I was going wrong.

Comment: RIght, Java regex won't ignore whitespace unless you have `Pattern.COMMENTS` or `(?x)` at the start of regex